# Express 4 POST - req.body.some_property is undefined

Tags: node.js, angular, express, post

I have looked over every recommended stack posting, the body-parser NPM documentation and various web blogs and can't resolve my issue

When I send a POST request from my Angular 4 app to my Node.JS / Express / MongoDB server req.body.data is undefined

**Data being POSTed:**

```
data = [{"startTime":"15:30", "endTime":"15:45"}]
```

**My Angular Method:**

```
getRange(data: object): Observable <Dataset[]> {
    console.log( "data being sent " + JSON.stringify(data) );
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    const url = 'http://localhost:3039/read/filterget';

    return this.http.post(url, data, options)
        .map(this.extractData )
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**My Express App**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var cors = require('cors');


var path = require("path");
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
, assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL, use the project name
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/clientserverExpSockIO';

var app = express();

// npm bodyParser/Express setup https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'applictaion/json' }) );
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')



app.post('/read/filterget', jsonParser, function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.headers);  
    if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body.data) );

    var params = req.body.data

    if (req.body.data)
    {
        console.log('data' + JSON.parse(data));
        params = JSON.parse(req.body.data);
    } else { console.log("params not set"); }


    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        console.log('mongodb connection opened');
        var collection = db.collection('json');

        if (params.startTime && params.endTime) {
            collection.find({ time: { $gt: params.startTime, $lt: 
        params.endTime } }).toArray(function (err, docs) {
                assert.equal(err, null);


                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                res.send(JSON.stringify(docs) /*, null, '\t'*/);

                // console.log("Found the following records");
                // console.log(docs)
                db.close();
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Start & End time not available');
            collection.find({}).toArray(function (err, docs) {
                assert.equal(err, null);
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                res.send(JSON.stringify(docs) /*, null, '\t'*/);
                db.close();
            });

        }
    });

});
```

**The output of console.log(req.headers) when the POST api is consumed:**

[image: headers output]

Comment: I would try `this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(data) ` first and I think http relies on a subscribe (or maybe that's just get)

Comment: There's a subscribe() set up in my angular controller that calls the service method loggerData.getRange() that you see above.  I tried to mirror the angular.io documentation for http POST observable --- is that what you were referring to?

Comment: `application/json` in body parser should be the correct mime type

Comment: Those 2 things were my initial thoughts, 1 stringify, 2 don't see subscribe,  (but I did assume this is probably just your service).  
But it looks like `applictaion` is misspelled as @Mr.Phoenix just stated.

Comment: Why use the `var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();` middleware ? I dont think it is needed. In my apps I just use the lines: `app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'applictaion/json' }) );
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); `

Comment: @PeterHauge the npm documentation for body-parser showed an example of POST JSON parsing using that technique - I might be mixing examples together

Comment: `data = [{"startTime":"15:30", "endTime":"15:45"}]` isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @robertklep - jsonlint.com passed it - Can you explain? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Jake did you mean that the data that you're sending is `[{"startTime":"15:30", "endTime":"15:45"}]`?

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix thanks - fixed the typo - same issue prevails - any other ideas?

Comment: @robertklep - yes - sorry if there was confusion

Comment: @Jake in that case, `req.body` will be an array, not an object that has a `data` property. So `params = req.body[0]` would work better.

Comment: try dump `req.body` in a `console.log` call and update your question all the changes

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix - i console.dir(req.body) and found i was looking for the wrong variable name. Thanks for finding that typo!

Comment: @robertklep that was the issue - i was looking for the wrong variable names - Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this.

**It turns out I was looking for the wrong property names when using req.body.some_property**

- Correct Property Name : **req.body[0].startTime**

**If this might be you:** Use console.dir(req.body) to see what exactly is being received by POST route

I thought the variable name (data) from my angular.http.post method would be sent to my express app and be a child of req.body, but it wasn't.  Only the data contained.

- I used console.dir(req.body) to see what my POST route was receiving
- The express app was receiving the correct JSON : [{"startTime":"15:30", "endTime":"15:45"}]
- I then used this: console.dir("Start Time: " + req.body[0].startTime) and that worked just fine.

Amateur mistake - Thank you all for your help and especially Mr.Phoenix who pointed out a typo which would have prevented me from this conclusion